# innerHTML but with multiple options to choose from

Tags: javascript, html

I am a fresh programmer and I'm trying to create my own quiz, I want to display only one set of a question and its answers at a time and would like to show a question counter. I am having trouble selection which one i want to display.

```
numberSpot.innerHTML = `Q${sequence}.${questionNumber}
```

I was trying to do something like this where sequence is equal to a variable and that variable is increased when you click next question. it wasn't working so i deleted the next question function to try and figure out what i could do.

```
//Questions and answers
class Question {
    constructor(question, questionNumber, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, correctAnswer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.questionNumber = questionNumber;
        this.answer1 = answer1;
        this.answer2 = answer2;
        this.answer3 = answer3;
        this.answer4 = answer4;
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    }
}


var q1 = new Question('How much do i weigh?', '1', '123lbs', '170lbs', '200lbs', '13lbs', '170lbs')
var q2 = new Question('how much do you weigh?', '2', '123lbs', '170lbs', '200lbs', '13lbs', '170lbs')


//the displaying function

var numberSpot = document.getElementById('qNumber');
var qSpot = document.getElementById('Question');
var answer1Spot = document.getElementById('answer1');
var answer2Spot = document.getElementById('answer2');
var answer3Spot = document.getElementById('answer3');
var answer4Spot = document.getElementById('answer4');

//score counter


//next question
```

Comment: Put all the questions in the HTML. Then change the `display` style to hide and show one question at a time, rather than changing `innerHTML`.

Comment: Your question is a little open ended. Do you have a specific problem, or are you looking for advice as to how to achieve the wider goal stated in your opening? Without trying to figure out exactly what it is you need answered, one tip I have is that you could definitely benefit from [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses your single-container approach.

(...Although it also includes some hints as to how you could make a separate container for each question and simply keep all the containers hidden except the one containing the current question.)

```js
class Question {
  constructor(question, questionNumber, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, correctAnswer) {
    this.question = question;
    this.questionNumber = questionNumber;
    this.answer1 = answer1;
    this.answer2 = answer2;
    this.answer3 = answer3;
    this.answer4 = answer4;
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
  }
}

const
  // Makes a short function name to get elements by id
  getById = (id) => document.getElementById(id),

  // Defines questions
  q1 = new Question('How much do I weigh?', '1', '123lbs', '170lbs', '200lbs', '13lbs', '170lbs'),
  q2 = new Question('how much do you weigh?', '2', '123lbs', '170lbs', '200lbs', '13lbs', '170lbs'),

  // Selects HTML elements
  container1   = getById('q1-container'), // HTML attributes should use lower case
  numberSpot  = getById('q-number'),
  qSpot       = getById('question'),
  answer1Spot = getById('answer1'),
  answer2Spot = getById('answer2'),
  answer3Spot = getById('answer3'),
  answer4Spot = getById('answer4');

// Inserts text into pre-selected elements
function populateElements(q){
  numberSpot.textContent = q.questionNumber + ")";
  qSpot.textContent = q.question;
  answer1Spot.textContent = "a) " + q.answer1;
  answer2Spot.textContent = "b) " + q.answer2;
  answer3Spot.textContent = "c) " + q.answer3;
  answer4Spot.textContent = "d) " + q.answer4;
}

// Stores questions in an array (not necessary, but may be more convenient)
const questions = [];
questions.push(q1, q2);
let currentQuestion = questions[0];

// Defines a function to get the next question in the array (untested)
const nextQuestion = () => {
  const ind = questions.findIndex( (q) =>
    q.questionNumber === currentQuestion.questionNumber
  );
  nextIfAny = (++ind < questions.length) ? questions[ind] : currentQuestion;
  return nextIfAny;
};

// Shows a particular container depending on the current question
if(currentQuestion = q1){
  container1.classList.remove("no-display");
}

// Shows a question in the single container
populateElements(currentQuestion);
```

```css
.answer{ padding-left: 1em; }
.no-display{ display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="q1-container">
  <span id="q-number"></span>
  <span id="question"></span>
  <div id="answer1" class="answer"></div>
  <div id="answer2" class="answer"></div>
  <div id="answer3" class="answer"></div>
  <div id="answer4" class="answer"></div>
</div>
```